# php <-> ajax Cross domain error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using `localhost devlopment`.

Request headers:

```
Host                localhost
If-Modified-Since   Sun, 31 May 2015 10:30:44 GMT
If-None-Match       "2486-5175e33a3f259"
Referer             http://localhost/front-page1/front-page/homepage.html
User-Agent          Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0)  
                    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

Whatever php page i access from ajax, it says

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/front-page1/front-page/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4:5309)
at uc (http://localhost/front-page1/front-page/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4:7333)
at x (http://localhost/front-page1/front-page/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4:10747)
at XMLHttpRequest.n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b 
(http://localhost/front-page1/front-page/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4:14577)
```

I don't understand how it became cross domain. And don't even understand the error. Please help me to solve this issue.

I just formatted my system and used `sql` scripts which are exported from my old system and all other codes are same.

Please let me know if other data required.

ERROR;

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die('{"message":"Database Error","status":"-1"}');
```

But this die is not getting executed.

Comment: Can you show the ajax call you do ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Added ajax call

Comment: How looks like `lib/registration_validate.php` if you access it with normal browser call?

Comment: Did the above script worked before you formatted your system and made usage of exported `sql` scripts?

Comment: @AMartinNo1 Yes. And @take, It displays none. `http://localhost/front-page1/front-page/lib/registration_validate.php`

Comment: Look at the sourcecode. It looks like there are some errors in your php script.

Comment: The script looks good and works as expected, You  might have error in the document ready or any other part of the page

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I really don't understand. I am calling this function from inside dom ready jquery function

Comment: As @take mentioned check your php script. I would also check your ajax script without the exported `sql`. If it's working you have to check your `sql`. Otherwise you possibly did not setup the system correctly.

Comment: @take updating code witht the line where problem occurs. I don't find a way to tackle it. But it's more with mysql

Comment: There is a syntax error in your JSON response. Use the network analyzer of your browser to see what the exact response is that you get from the server, or simply open the URL in a new tab and inspect that.